# WebKit - что он делает?

Tags: webkit

Единственное, что я понял на данный момент - WebKit - это библиотека С++, которая каким то образом, если я правильно понял - принимает на вход полноценную HTML страницу и как то ее рендерит/визуализирует ??

А если в HTML используется Javacscript, Jquery и Ajax - библиотека тоже их сама обрабатывает что ли ? И ajax`ы сама инициирует ?

Если не сложно подскажите, есть какие то простенькие примеры/уроки с чего бы можно было начать, чтобы понять, как WebKit работает и что делает ?